# How to check if data source is empty in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

so I have a formula that looks like this:

```
ToText({ProjectedHours.StartDate},{?Pm-?ShortDateFormat})  + " - " + ToText({ProjectedHours.EndDate},{?Pm-?ShortDateFormat})
```

ProjectedHours is the data source that I'm passing in from C#/.NET. The problem is that it is possible for ProjectedHours to be empty. Is there a way for me to basically to conditionally execute the code above only if ProjectedHours is not empty?

I actually tried this as well. Since I'm using C#/.NET, I can detect if ProjectedHours is empty or not. If it is, I simply set a parameter called HideProjectedHours to true, else false. And in Crystal, I have the following code:

```
If {?Pm-?HideProjectedPaidHours} = false Then
ToText({ProjectedHours.StartDate},{?Pm-?ShortDateFormat})  + " - " + ToText({ProjectedHours.EndDate},{?Pm-?ShortDateFormat})
```

However, this doesn't work either and I get the error message "Too many arguments have been given to this function. Details: errorKind

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It seemed that in my C# code, I could simply not add a data source to my subreport if the data source is empty (count = 0). By not adding a data source to the subreport, I stopped seeing the error message. Basically, my orginally problem was that a formula in a subreport was throwing a crystal reports error even though I was suppressing that subreport.

```
if (ProjectedHours.Count > 0)
{
     Report.Subreports["ProjectedHours"].SetDataSource(ProjectedHours);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First look of your question seems there is problem is with the `ToText` function where arguments are more.

Your formula seems to be you are using `dates` in totext so check the documentation to correct the syntax.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsawshlp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc%2Fhtml%2Ftopic666.html

If you are trying for specific format... update your question and let me know

Answer (score 0):

in your C# code:

```
if ((DT != null) & DT.Rows.Count > 0) {
return;
}
```

or in your report select the column that it maybe return null or empty and suppress it using

```
isnull({ProjectedHours.ColumnName})
```